# Error Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check the address and try again, when trying to create file from Google drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I receive the following error message when I try to create a Google App Script, "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check the address and try again."

In the forums it talks about being logged into multiple accounts. I am only logged into one Google account. Any ideas on what else can cause this? Is there something in the Google Security Portal (Admin Portal) that may be causing this?

I'm not creating the script inside a spreadsheet, but within a Google Drive Folder, New->more->Google App Script.

Comment: Please check whether you have permission to the referenced sheet in apps script code.

Comment: Share the code if possible.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I'm not creating the script inside a spreadsheet, but within a Google Drive Folder, New->more->Google App Script. Thanks again.

Comment: There is no code to share, it won't let me create a Google App Script. I get the above error.

Comment: Does it work if you log into your account in an incognito session? Were you able to do this before or is it the first time you have created a script? Can you create a script from http://script.google.com/ ?

Comment: Thanks again for the response. It gives the same error when using incognito mode. This is the first time I was trying it outside of Sheets. I can create a script no problem in Sheets. I can also create it going via scripts.google.com.

Comment: It's when I drive to create it inside of Drive that I get the error.

Comment: As detailed in the linked answer, if you are experiencing this issue please star [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/169584644)