# Appscript from drive throws "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check the address and try again" for a week

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I tried to do this:
[image: Failed attempt at an appscript]

But I always get this:

> "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check the address and try again
> [image: Proof of failure]

Do I have to enable it somewhere secret somehow.

Comment: https://script.google.com/

Comment: Yes, the new title is much better, or at least more professional.  I think we should choose articles.  Either "a" or "the" week, depending on preference.

Comment: Feel free to [edit] it as per your preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It seems to be a bug, I am having the same issue and it seems that [other users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64069886/google-app-script-error-sorry-unable-to-open-the-file-at-this-time-please-chec) also do.

There is already an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/169584644) about it on Public Issue Tracker -  give it a "star" to increase visibility.

In the meantime use the workaround as suggested by [TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster) and create your scripts from `script.google.com` instead of `drive.google.com`.

Answer (score 1):

On Google's *Docs Editors Help* [Nathan Alvesinho suggested](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/13014914?hl=en&msgid=13089945) that multiple accounts may have something to do with it. I also have multiple accounts. I used the Sign out of all accounts button on my google profile. I signed back in to only one account, and it worked. Not ideal, but it helped me.